# PHP parse error when use []

Tags: php

The code is

```
// Get singleton (first value from row with single value)
static function singleton($arg, $params = false) {
    return pg_fetch_row(SQL($arg, $params))[0];
}
```

The error message is

> 2014-02-19 12:54:23: (mod_fastcgi.c.2701) FastCGI-stderr: PHP message: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /var/www/blockexplorer.com/htdocs/includes/sql.inc on line 69

I think there is a config that can fix it.

Comment: What is the version of your PHP you using ?

Comment: It seems like a PHP5.3, that not supports this. So, you need to place result of function pg_fetch_row into variable first - as @Mario Jonathan calls it.

Comment: Your syntax is correct, but that's a very new feature of PHP that (IIRC) requires at least version 5.4. I can't find it in the change logs, but it's better (for now) to count on that _not_ working unless your developing for a specific platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on PHP version you are using. If you are using PHP 5.4 or above then your code will not give error otherwise you will have to store the result in a variable and use it.

Reference : [PHP 5.4](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-54-is-here-what-you-must-know--net-24292)

Look for "Array Dereferencing" here.

Answer (score 2):

Put the result of the function in a variable

```
static function singleton($arg, $params = false) {
    $foo = pg_fetch_row(SQL($arg, $params));
    return $foo[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not support anonymous arrays. Use an named array instead:

```
static function singleton($arg, $params = false) {
    $row=pg_fetch_row(SQL($arg, $params));
    return $row[0];
}
```

Comment: Array dereferencing _is_ supported by PHP, but only in 5.4+.